# Unable to clear value of element in template driven form when mask format is changed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, input-mask, ngx-mask

I have a text box, where I need to change the mask format based on user input and clear the text box. If I change the mask format, the text box is not getting cleared, and if I remove the condition of mask format, the text box is getting cleared

```
html

<input type="text" mask="{{maskFormat}}" [(ngModel)]="empId" />

<button (click)="toggleMask()">Change Mask</button>
```

```
TS

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  maskFormat: string = '000';
  empId: string;

  toggleMask(): void {

    if (this.maskFormat.length == 3) {
      this.maskFormat = "000000";
    }
    else {
      this.maskFormat = "000";
    }


    this.empId = "";

  }

}
```

Note: I am using [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) package

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-issue)

Comment: Code should be included in the question, as text in a code block, not as a link to a site.  From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/24123657)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's due to the `ngx-mask` module performing some recalculation of the value and then setting the model value after your `this.empId = "";` is run.

By adding a `setTimeout` function with a zero timer, you will force Angular to wait one life cycle before it set's the value, thus letting the `ngx-mask` code run before your code.

`setTimeout(() => { this.empId = null }, 0);`

This is not an elegant solution but without looking into the `ngx-mask` module, it solves your problem.

[Here's a working StackBlitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-issue-dj9uny)